# Use timers in android for custom navigation bar

Tags: android

I'm making a custom navigation bar for android. Whenever I touch the screen, the custom navigation bar will appear and after 5 seconds, it will disappear( by removing the navigation bar view when time is done). If I use navigation bar before 5 seconds, it should reset the timer. I'm not able to implement the disappearing part work because I don't know how to handle timing event. I use Timer class to do so but the application crashes because in the run method(), I remove the View which is not allowed as the thread which created the view must be the one to remove it. Any ideas how to handle timing event in the current thread.

09-15 11:26:14.033: W/dalvikvm(30092): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e8ba8)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092): Process: wei.mark.example, PID: 30092

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6024)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:853)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4320)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10935)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10890)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:201)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:344)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:575)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.widget.ImageView.onDetachedFromWindow(ImageView.java:1244)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12620)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2585)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3845)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3818)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3750)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at wei.mark.example.MyService$Task.run(MyService.java:127)

09-15 11:26:14.043: E/AndroidRuntime(30092):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the logcat to see the crash? You should use `postDelayed` to handle your timer, and reset it when you receive a touch event.

Comment: I have added the logcat also.